# Input field function when aggregating data in node and mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, aggregate

I am trying to develop a data aggregation feature for an application. The user should be able to enter a name and it'll search the database collection for that name and return the collection.
I am trying to implement it using node.js but i am confused as to how to pass a parameter for the name.

Controller:

```
exports.DAFacility_author_search = (req, res) => {
  DAFacility.aggregate([
    [
      {
        '$match': {
          'author': author
        }
      }
    ]
  ]).then((DAFacility) => {
    res.send(DAFacility);
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    res.send(e);
  });
};
```

Route:

```
router.get('/DAFacilityAuthor', DAFacilityController.DAFacility_author_search)
```

For the `'author': author` i am trying to use author as the variable name but i dont exactly know how to structure the controller and router to take in a parameter so that i can retrieve a value on postman.
Any help would be great
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that your request in postman will be something like:

```json
{
    "author": "foo",
    ...
}
```

When your request is received by the API, the body is available in your `req` object in the controller, so, if you want to use `author` field in your aggregate, you simply access: `req.body.author`.

Your controller could have the next structure:

```js
export const DAFacilityController = {
    DAFacility_author_search: (req, res) => {
        DAFacility.aggregate([
            {'$match': {'author': req.body.author}}
        ])
    .then((DAFacility) => {
        res.send(DAFacility);
    }).catch((e) => {
        res.send(e);
    });
    },

    DAFacility_another_method: (req, res) => {...},
}
```

The router is ok:

```js
router.get('/DAFacilityAuthor', DAFacilityController.DAFacility_author_search);
router.get('/DAFacilityAuthor/<something>', DAFacilityController.DAFacility_another_method);
```

I hope I helped

Comment: You most definately did. Thank you!